# Operating system not found after installing linux mint

Tags: linux, multi-boot, linux-mint, dualboot

I installed linux mint along side windows 10 on an old laptop from 2012 (i7-2670QM),

after installation,
removed mint flash drive -> enter -> laptop rebbot,
and getting `Operating sytem not found`

Is there anything I can do to fix this, or do I have to try to install something else like ubuntu, or windows 10 again.

Comment: I haven't installed Mint for a couple of years as I tend to prefer Debian. At the end did it ask where to install the boot loader? If so, did you choose `/dev/sda` (good) or something with a number on the end like `/dev/sda1` (probably the default, and not so good)?

Comment: it didn't ask, I used all default options, at the beginning, but there was no question about the boot loader, looking online it seems to be an UEFI thing, which my laptop bios doesn't have

Comment: Does the BIOS see see the disk? It should only display disks with boot.

Comment: Do you see this in the PC disk or the USB flash ?

Comment: According to what you say, the problem happens when booting without the flash drive. So I'm asking about the internal disk.

Comment: My bios is very minimal, I see it sees the "Hard Disk Drive 250GB", but I don't see anywhere the individual partitioned disks, in Boot Priority I can select "Inernal Hard Disk Drive"

Comment: I've created an ubuntu flash with etcher and it was also partitioned so I guess that's not the issue, the ubuntu flash won't boot btw

Comment: @ChrisDavies I've installed Debian12, and now it works, I can even select between Windows 10 and Debian when it starts

Answer (score -1):

I installed Debian 12 as suggested in the comments,
the boot loader has been restored (GRUB),

I can load both Debian and Windows 10 now.

(windows has done some repairing before the 1st start, about 3 times before 1st successful load)